# ISSET Php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

guys how come whenever i click submit button on my form without any data in the textbox, it's saying  echo 'Either your username, or email is already taken!'; . How come it still passes through this despite of the form not having any data? what could be the best explanation?

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $extract= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username'");

    $resultq = mysql_num_rows($extract);
    if($resultq > 0)
    {
       echo 'Either your username, or email is already taken!';
       return;
    }

}
```

Please hi'm stuck with this line for 12 hours, i can't seem to move on :(

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: best explanation? That you check what the content is of both variables $username and $email and check whether or not these exist in your DB

Answer (score 2):

`isset` renders true for empty string. it checks the existence of a variable. Here is a [detailed explanation](http://themessycode.blogspot.com/2013/08/analysis-of-isset-and-empty-functions.html).

You should use `if (trim($_POST['username']) != "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $extract= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username'");

    $resultq = mysql_num_rows($extract);
    if($resultq > 0)
    {
       echo 'Either your username, or email is already taken!';
       return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `!empty` :

If you want to check both `username` OR `email` if `already exist` you also need to check `email` in `select` query

```
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $extract= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username' OR email='$email'");

        $resultq = mysql_num_rows($extract);
        if($resultq > 0)
        {
           echo 'Either your username, or email is already taken!';
           return false;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Accept';
            return true;
        }
    }
```